# How should Android dialog source be organized in an application?

Tags: android, dialog, organization

My application contains many Dialog windows. It has gotten to the point that the source seems overwhelming. I am looking for opinions about the best way to segregate Dialog source. I am relatively new to Java, so I am assuming that I can put them in a separate class. However, the exact way to do this in Android alludes me. May someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I think it would help if you specified your problem a bit more. How many Activities are there in your app? Are the Dialogs each specific to one Activity, or is there a Dialog which might open from different Activities?

Comment: All Dialog windows pertain to one Activity, and they can't be accessed outside of it. I am just looking for a clever way to encapsulate all Dialog windows in a convenient way. Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can create dialogue by extending dialogue as follows 
1. Create a Layout.xml for customDialog
Create a new layout which contains the view. in this example i have used edittext and button.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/EditText01" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Enter your name" android:layout_width="250dip"></EditText>

<Button android:id="@+id/Button01" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="click"></Button>
```

1. Create a Custom Dialog Class. 
   a. Create a class extends the dialog class 
   b. Create a Event Handler Interface as a member
   c. Use the custom layout in onCreate Method.

   ```
   public class MyCustomDialog extends Dialog {

   public interface ReadyListener {
       public void ready(String name);
   }

   private String name;
   private ReadyListener readyListener;
   EditText etName;

   public MyCustomDialog(Context context, String name, 
           ReadyListener readyListener) {
       super(context);
       this.name = name;
       this.readyListener = readyListener;
   }

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.mycustomdialog);
       setTitle("Enter your Name ");
       Button buttonOK = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
       buttonOK.setOnClickListener(new OKListener());
       etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
   }

   private class OKListener implements android.view.View.OnClickListener {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           readyListener.ready(String.valueOf(etName.getText()));
           MyCustomDialog.this.dismiss();
       }
   }
   ```

   }
2. Create a MainActivity and Implement the CustomDialog

   public class MainActivity extends Activity {
       /** Called when the activity is first created. */
       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.main);
           MyCustomDialog myDialog = new MyCustomDialog(this, "",
                   new OnReadyListener());
           myDialog.show();
       }
       private class OnReadyListener implements MyCustomDialog.ReadyListener {
           @Override
           public void ready(String name) {
               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
       }
   }